# How to add a button to admin panel that adds a predefined paragraph into an article?

Tags: php, wordpress

I am using WordPress to write articles.

Quite often I need to add the same paragraph in every article I write.

Would it be possible to create a button in administrator menu that would add predefined text to the end of an article?

Comment: Yes it would. You can create a custom metabox with a button that triggers Javascript to add a paragraph into the editor.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code to add A button to the Post editor text tab

```
add_action( 'admin_print_footer_scripts', 'default_content_add_quicktags' );
function default_content_add_quicktags() {
    if ( wp_script_is( 'quicktags' ) ) {
?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function doThis(){
             QTags.insertContent( 'Some Default Text' );
        }
        QTags.addButton( 'default_content_id', 'Default Content', doThis, '', 'default_content', 'Default content', 100 );
    </script>
<?php
    }
}
```

A new button named "**Default Content**" will be added to buttons in the text tab.

You can add the default content in `QTags.insertContent()` which will be called when the button is clicked.